# Google Ads data in BigQuery - How to link p_ExtensionsSitelinks with p_AdStats?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-ads-api

This is a question addressed to users of Google Ads data in BigQuery.

My goal is to create a dashboard displaying all ad extensions (Sitelinks, callouts ...) and their results.

In BigQuery, we have this dataset called "rawdata" imported from Google Ads. I noticed that ad extensions have specific tables and are not in generic tables like "*p_Ad*" or "*p_AdStats*". Instead we can find them in *p_ExtensionsCallouts*, *p_ExtensionsSitelinks*.

But in *p_ExtensionsSitelinks* we only find ad texts, no figures, no results. So I need to link to another table containing results. **CreativeId** in *p_AdStats* seemed to be the key between my results and the id in my sitelinks table.

I tried to join *p_AdStats* to *p_ExtensionsSitelinks*, on **p_AdStats.CreativeId** = **p_ExtensionsSitelinks.Id**, but no success. **Id** in *p_ExtensionsSitelinks* seems to be a very specific id, not found in *p_Ad*.

[Screenshot of p_ExtensionsSitelinks Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DX3jE.png)

Does anyone have already encountered this problem please?

Thank you very much.

Cheers, Julien

Comment: `CreativeId` sounds like it refers to image ads, so I don't think it's the key you are looking for.
Interestingly, the extensions tables aren't even listed in the [Google Ads reports to BigQuery table mapping](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/adwords-transformation)...

Comment: Hi @dorian, I am 99% confident that CreativeId refers to Search ads as well as Display (by looking at p_Ad)
And you are right it is not listed in the mapping page, maybe we get it as a beta function, because we have two accounts and thoses mysterious tables are retrieved only from 1 account, the biggest one...

Comment: I got that wrong and you are right, CreativeId does definitely refer to all types of ads. I also ran a BigQuery export for one of our Ads accounts and didn't get any extensions tables—so it might indeed be a beta that you are enrolled in. Sorry I can't be of more help.